# Is it possible to run a single test of a test class in Grails?

Tags: grails, testing

We have a very large suite of tests for an app we are developing. I already know how to run specific test classes in either Unit or Integration, e.g.:

```
grails test-app -integration FooIntegrationTest
```

When developing new integration tests, it can take a long time to run through an entire class (say if FooIntegrationTest has 100 tests). I want to run only a specific single test out of the entire test battery.

Answer (score 1):

```
grails test-app integration: FooIntegrationTest.testSample
```

should do if `testSample()` is one of the test case.

Comment: What is the difference between the colon (:) and the dash (-) BTW? They both seem to work interchangeably - is one deprecated do you know? I can't up vote your answer cuz I have less than 15 points. Which is really really annoying. LOL!

Comment: I am not sure but vaguely remember `-` was convention used in former versions of Grails. I have started using `:` from Grails 2. You may be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know why it never occurred to me to try this, but I just experimented and discovered you actually can do this via:

```
grails -test-app -integration FooIntegrationTest.testCrossFoo420
```

That actually runs just the integration test `testCrossFoo420()` in `FooIntegrationTest.Groovy` which is going to save me a bunch of time.

I guess I'll leave this out here in case it helps others. Back to coding!